# SQL to Snowflake - Converting Nested select (values

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Would anyone know the Snowflake equiv for this type of SQL query? Tried CORR in snowflake but that didn't work.

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY x.LMID
                               ORDER BY (   SELECT MIN(val)
                                            FROM (   VALUES ( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.OpenDT, x.Booked)))
                                                            , ( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.CloseDT, x.Booked)))) AS value (
                                            val ) )
                                        , v.LastVersion DESC ) AS RowNum
           , (   SELECT MIN(val)
                 FROM (   VALUES ( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.OpenDT, x.Booked)))
                                 , ( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.CloseDT, x.Booked)))) AS value ( val ) )
    FROM (   SELECT lm.LMID
                    , lm.ID
                    , lm.Booked
                    , req.RequestId AS RequestID
             FROM #Pop lm
                 INNER JOIN dbo.request req ON req.ServicerLoanNumber = lm.ID
                 INNER JOIN dbo.RequestHistory rh ON rh.RequestId = req.RequestId
                                                                AND req.LastVersion = rh.Version
                                                                AND (   rh.FinalDispositionTypeId = 1
                                                                        OR rh.RequestStatusTypeId = 20 )
             WHERE lm.Booked >= lm.AddDate
                   AND YEAR(lm.Booked) >= 2013 ) x

        INNER JOIN dbo.Request v ON v.RequestId = x.RequestID
        INNER JOIN dbo.RequestHistory rh ON rh.RequestId = v.RequestId
                                                       AND rh.Version = v.LastVersion;
```

Comment: So which part of that SQL statement are you having trouble with and what is the actual issue you are facing? It would probably be a good approach to start with the inner SELECT, get that to work and then move outwards query by query. Also, what do you mean by “this type of query”? Of what do you think your query is a type?

Comment: Please share some sample data and desired results - not just a query dump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so if I rework you SQL so I can see the layer of it:

```
Select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( 
        PARTITION BY x.LMID 
        ORDER BY (
            SELECT 
                MIN(val)
            FROM (   
                VALUES 
                    ( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.OpenDT, x.Booked))),
                    ( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.CloseDT, x.Booked)))
            ) AS value(val) 
        ), v.LastVersion DESC 
    ) AS RowNum
    ,(   
        SELECT 
            MIN(val)
        FROM (   
            VALUES 
                ( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.OpenDT, x.Booked))),
                ( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.CloseDT, x.Booked)))
        ) AS value(val)
    )
FROM (   
    SELECT 
        lm.LMID
        ,lm.ID
        ,lm.Booked
        ,req.RequestId AS RequestID
    FROM #Pop as lm
    INNER JOIN dbo.request as req 
        ON req.ServicerLoanNumber = lm.ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.RequestHistory as rh 
        ON rh.RequestId = req.RequestId
            AND req.LastVersion = rh.Version
            AND ( rh.FinalDispositionTypeId = 1 OR
                  rh.RequestStatusTypeId = 20 )
    WHERE lm.Booked >= lm.AddDate
        AND YEAR(lm.Booked) >= 2013
) as x
INNER JOIN dbo.Request as v 
    ON v.RequestId = x.RequestID
INNER JOIN dbo.RequestHistory as rh 
    ON rh.RequestId = v.RequestId
        AND rh.Version = v.LastVersion;
```

so you have a temp table in what appears T-SQL, and two dbo tables.

so we can make some fake tables as CTE's to test this a little:

```
with pop(lmid, id, booked, AddDate) as (
    select * from values
        (1,10,'2023-11-14'::date, '2023-11-14'::date)
), request(ServicerLoanNumber, RequestId, LastVersion) as (
    select * from values 
        (10,100, 1000)
),RequestHistory(RequestId, version, FinalDispositionTypeId, RequestStatusTypeId, opendt, closedt) as (
    select * from values 
        (100, 1000, 1, 0, '2023-11-14'::date, '2023-11-14'::date)
)
Select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( 
        PARTITION BY x.LMID 
        ORDER BY (
            SELECT 
                MIN(val)
            FROM (   
                VALUES 
                    ( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.OpenDT, x.Booked))),
                    ( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.CloseDT, x.Booked)))
            ) AS value(val) 
        ), v.LastVersion DESC 
    ) AS RowNum
    ,(   
        SELECT 
            MIN(val)
        FROM (   
            VALUES 
                ( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.OpenDT, x.Booked))),
                ( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.CloseDT, x.Booked)))
        ) AS value(val)
    )
FROM (   
    SELECT 
        lm.LMID
        ,lm.ID
        ,lm.Booked
        ,req.RequestId
    FROM Pop as lm
    INNER JOIN request as req 
        ON req.ServicerLoanNumber = lm.ID
    INNER JOIN RequestHistory as rh 
        ON rh.RequestId = req.RequestId
            AND req.LastVersion = rh.Version
            AND ( rh.FinalDispositionTypeId = 1 OR
                  rh.RequestStatusTypeId = 20 )
    WHERE lm.Booked >= lm.AddDate
        AND YEAR(lm.Booked) >= 2013
) as x
INNER JOIN Request as v 
    ON v.RequestId = x.RequestID
INNER JOIN RequestHistory as rh 
    ON rh.RequestId = v.RequestId
        AND rh.Version = v.LastVersion;
```

gives the error:

> Invalid expression [ABS(DATE_DIFFDATEINDAYS('2023-11-14', '2023-11-14'))] in VALUES clause

which makes sense as Snowflake only accepts constant expressions in VALUES.

so if we start to move code around to make simple to see the chain of code, the sub-select `x` can be moved into a CTE:

```
with pop(lmid, id, booked, AddDate) as (
    select * from values
        (1,10,'2023-11-14'::date, '2023-11-14'::date)
), request(ServicerLoanNumber, RequestId, LastVersion) as (
    select * from values 
        (10,100, 1000)
),RequestHistory(RequestId, version, FinalDispositionTypeId, RequestStatusTypeId, opendt, closedt) as (
    select * from values 
        (100, 1000, 1, 0, '2023-11-14'::date, '2023-11-14'::date)
), cte_x as (
    SELECT 
        lm.LMID
        ,lm.ID
        ,lm.Booked
        ,req.RequestId
    FROM Pop as lm
    INNER JOIN request as req 
        ON req.ServicerLoanNumber = lm.ID
    INNER JOIN RequestHistory as rh 
        ON rh.RequestId = req.RequestId
            AND req.LastVersion = rh.Version
            AND ( rh.FinalDispositionTypeId = 1 OR
                  rh.RequestStatusTypeId = 20 )
    WHERE lm.Booked >= lm.AddDate
        AND YEAR(lm.Booked) >= 2013
)

Select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( 
        PARTITION BY x.LMID 
        ORDER BY (
            SELECT 
                MIN(val)
            FROM (   
                VALUES 
                    ( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.OpenDT, x.Booked))),
                    ( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.CloseDT, x.Booked)))
            ) AS value(val) 
        ), v.LastVersion DESC 
    ) AS RowNum
    ,(   
        SELECT 
            MIN(val)
        FROM (   
            VALUES 
                ( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.OpenDT, x.Booked))),
                ( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.CloseDT, x.Booked)))
        ) AS value(val)
    )
FROM cte_x as x
INNER JOIN Request as v 
    ON v.RequestId = x.RequestID
INNER JOIN RequestHistory as rh 
    ON rh.RequestId = v.RequestId
        AND rh.Version = v.LastVersion;
```

now this block is repeated twice, so that could be done once, (it also is the problem line)

```
SELECT 
    MIN(val)
FROM (   
    VALUES 
        ( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.OpenDT, x.Booked))),
        ( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.CloseDT, x.Booked)))
) AS value(val)
```

anyways, given this is fixed, we can swap to LEAST instead of MIN:

```
LEAST( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.OpenDT, x.Booked)),
       ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.CloseDT, x.Booked)))
```

least behaves poorly if any input is NULL, thus as long as all three values (booked, opendt, closedt) are not NULL this is safe,

thus it can be written:

```
with pop(lmid, id, booked, AddDate) as (
    select * from values
        (1,10,'2023-11-14'::date, '2023-11-14'::date)
), request(ServicerLoanNumber, RequestId, LastVersion) as (
    select * from values 
        (10,100, 1000)
),RequestHistory(RequestId, version, FinalDispositionTypeId, RequestStatusTypeId, opendt, closedt) as (
    select * from values 
        (100, 1000, 1, 0, '2023-11-14'::date, '2023-11-14'::date)
), cte_x as (
    SELECT 
        lm.LMID
        ,lm.ID
        ,lm.Booked
        ,req.RequestId
    FROM Pop as lm
    INNER JOIN request as req 
        ON req.ServicerLoanNumber = lm.ID
    INNER JOIN RequestHistory as rh 
        ON rh.RequestId = req.RequestId
            AND req.LastVersion = rh.Version
            AND ( rh.FinalDispositionTypeId = 1 OR
                  rh.RequestStatusTypeId = 20 )
    WHERE lm.Booked >= lm.AddDate
        AND YEAR(lm.Booked) >= 2013
)
Select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( 
        PARTITION BY x.LMID 
        ORDER BY LEAST( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.OpenDT, x.Booked)),
                   ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.CloseDT, x.Booked))), v.LastVersion DESC 
    ) AS RowNum
    ,LEAST( ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.OpenDT, x.Booked)),
                   ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, rh.CloseDT, x.Booked))) as min_days
FROM cte_x as x
INNER JOIN Request as v 
    ON v.RequestId = x.RequestID
INNER JOIN RequestHistory as rh 
    ON rh.RequestId = v.RequestId
        AND rh.Version = v.LastVersion;
```

which gives:

[image]

which is about what I would expect, I dislike doing the LEAST twice, and would be inclined to do that is a CTE, but I assume there is more complex logic also needed, that has been stripped out, so will leave it here.